# Xslt produce some <name> tags with CDATA and some <name> tags without?

Tags: xslt, cdata, moodle

Summary: I'm using xslt to convert data, and need to produce some  tags with CDATA inside and some  tags without. Is escaping the CDATA sections my only option?

I'm attempting to convert data I already have in xml to [Moodle Xml](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Moodle_XML) for importing. The final product needs to include some Html, which the [Moodle Xml doc](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Moodle_XML) specifically says needs to be contained in CDATA.

**Desired Output:**

```
<question>
  <name>
    <text>FooName</text>
  </name>
  <questiontext format="html">
    <text><![CDATA[<img src="1.png">]]></text>
  </questiontext>
</question>
```

I gave this a try using the following code (trimmed down, but will include the data from my input xml file):

**Method 1, nothing special**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <question>
      <name>
        <text>FooName</text>
      </name>
      <questiontext format="html">
        <text><![CDATA[<img src="1.png">]]></text>
      </questiontext>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And got...

**Bad Output from Method 1**

```
<question>
  <name>
    <text>FooName</text>
  </name>
  <questiontext format="html">
    <text>&lt;img src="1.png"&gt;</text>
  </questiontext>
</question>
```

So I look up the [xslt documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-XML-Output-Method) and [some SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265334/how-to-access-variable-in-cdata-from-xslt), which seem to say I have 2 options:

1. Do nothing, CDATA gets escaped.
2. use `cdata-section-elements ="text"` to auto-generate cdata sections inside  tags
3. Generate CDATA sections by hand, using `disable-output-escaping="yes"`

Ok, autogeneration sounds good. Lets try that:

**Method 2 adding `cdata-section-elements="text"`**

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" cdata-section-elements="text"/>
```

**Bad Output from `cdata-section-elements ="text"`**:

```
<question>
  <name>
    <text><![CDATA[FooName]]></text>
  </name>
  <questiontext format="html">
    <text><![CDATA[<img src="1.png">]]></text>
  </questiontext>
</question>
```

So 2 isn't an option because there are other  elements I do NOT want containing CDATA, in a schema I don't control.

This leaves me with option 3, escaping it by hand. My question then is: Is option 3 my only option? Is there anything else I can do to get my desired output using XSLT? not using XSLT?

Comment: Have you verified that using method 2 (`cdata-section-elements="text"`) breaks Moodle?  If it parses XML correctly, the "extra" CDATA sections shouldn't bother it.  Actually, if it parses XML correctly then it should also handle escaped HTML as well.  If neither of these works then the problem is in Moodle, not XML or XSLT.

Answer (score 5):

I've found this method on http://neehouse.com/code/xslt/cdata_string_output.aspx

**Code**

```
<no1>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="data/NO1"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
</no1>
```

**Output**

```
<no1><![CDATA[xxxxxxxxxxxx]]></no1>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, your Method 1 and Method 2 do not produced the result you want.

Because of the extremely strange and rare requirement for the output lexical appearance, you are left with only the 3rd method.

Answer (score 0):

As Dimitre has answer, your requirement is strange because in XML elements names have schema meaning. If `text` elements schema allows CDATA, this is so for all `text` elements.

One way to do what you want with extra element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="xhtml:div"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <question>
            <name>
                <text>FooName</text>
            </name>
            <questiontext format="html">
                <text>
                     <xhtml:div><![CDATA[<img src="1.png">]]></xhtml:div>
                </text>
            </questiontext>
        </question>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output (with any input):

```
<question xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <name>
        <text>FooName</text>
    </name>
    <questiontext format="html">
        <text>
            <xhtml:div><![CDATA[<img src="1.png">]]></xhtml:div>
        </text>
    </questiontext>
</question>
```